# How to call a class constructor from a Qt custom library

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a custom Qt library and now I want to test some classes in that library.  However, when I try to instantiate an object by calling the constructor of an included header file, the program crashes immediately on startup and I also can't debug. Furthermore, the Unit tests work when I comment the constructor call out.

Comment: MCVE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please excuse me but i don't think code is relevant here. This is just informational just someone to describe to me if it is possible and if yes how.

Comment: You're making constrains that we can't simply accept. When you say ,for example, "I also can't debug", you think you're making things clearer, but you aren't. So either make it clear on how the situation is so that people can help you, or don't waste your time expecting people to accept all your assumptions and constraints. Try to read your question from the perspective of someone who knows nothing about what you're doing. Yes, we need an example to understand.

Comment: Give us more information to begin with. OS, IDE, dynamic or static lib?
I can only assume, that you have not connected your library to your main executable (via project settings), adding include to header file is not enough. Please, read this: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html, but again, if you are using Visual Studio, for example, it can be different.